# Get access token LinkedIn Api

Tags: linkedin-api

I am developing a module to integrate the company's website with several social networks.
I've done it with Instagram, Facebook and Twitter.
I wanted to do the same with LinkedIn.

When i call the API to generate the token i receive the error message:

[Postman call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqIYU.png)

I have searched everywhere and i don't found any indication where i need to go to ask permission to create tokens.

The support of LinkedIn tell me to came here...

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try reading more about the LinkedIn client credentials flow in the below link. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/context

> If your application needs to access APIs that are not member specific, use the Client Credential Flow. Your application cannot access these APIs by default. Learn more about LinkedIn Developer Enterprise products to request permission to the Client Credential Flow.

As highlighted in the document, an application will not be having access to client credentials by default and you will have to request access exclusively based on your business need. Most of the LinkedIn APIs require three-legged authentication fetch member related data since most of the data request is directly or indirectly related to a member or owned by a member.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).